# Library project: how to override properties?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I created a project, that is a finished product. Now I have different user, for them I have to change somethings such as app colors, name, service URL.

Now I made my project as a library and for different user I created different modules. And these modules are adding my project as libray.

**Now my questions are**

1. How to update my service url per client. Such as client url that is used in library project exist inside Common file. How to change/Override this?
2. How to change colors, and other resources?
3. What is a best way of creating library that allows to override its properties? And how to do that?

I know there is a complete link on android page to how to create a library. I have done that. But I really not getting how to override properties of library. How to give them a way to get updated by modules that are using them.

Comment: You can use resources and the app module can define resources with the same name.

Comment: is there any other way of doing so ?